# Website consuming high bandwidth

Tags: php, codeigniter, cpanel, bandwidth-throttling

My website page size is less than 1mb, including third party links.

But in cpanel awstats it is showing bandwidth : 11199.72 KB/Visit.

I am unable to understand where my bandwidth goes.

I talked to hosting company they are telling there is no ddos or any other attack on website, I also try by switching to another server, but the problem is same.

Can anyone suggest me a tool, who help me to findout the issue.
My website is written in codeigniter, with database caching and webpage caching

Comment: Are you using Javascript frameworks (Jquery, Angular), CSS frameworks (Foundation, Bootstrap), using a lot of images?

Comment: I am using jquery, with around 30 images on homepage only

Comment: What's the size of each image? Because if you have 30 images, each one of is about 300kb(3 mb), there you have near 10.000kb (10mb)

Comment: each image is under 13kb

Comment: but a visit 11199.72 is too high, I want to resolve it

Comment: Do you have a public URL?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use logs to view bandwidth that might help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool, it have some recommendations in page weight

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/